# Ship log files using Kafka Producer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to create a python script to ship files from a Virtual Machine and send them to a kafka broker.
to make it simple:

- I have log files in this ip address: **VM1** **10.10.10.1**
- I would like to create a kafka producer (using python) to ship files from **VM1**
- Kafka is installed on another virtual machine: **VM2 10.10.10.2**

***limitations***

1. I can't install any tools on the **VM1**
2. I can only use user/pwd to get access to **VM1**

I think that I need to create a connector? Can we reuse something like **connect-file-sink.properties** and specify the folder+ip where a file is stored in an external machine: **VM1**

There is another tools to do that?

Comment: What's MDP? Do you have SSH access to the server? What OS is it running?

Comment: Yes I have an SSH access to the server and I can do an sftp. The client server is running on Centos. (I edited my question MDP=> pwd)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of existing tools that will do this, e.g. [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) which supports [output to Kafka](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html), [Fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/), etc.

These are all simple to setup with simple configuration files. The trickiest bit will probably be your networking—just make sure you've [configured Kafka's listeners correctly](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/).

Comment: Yes, I have used filebeat before and I know how to configure it but the problem is that I can't install filebeat on the client server (where the log files are stored)
I can only get the ip address and user/pwd to do an sftp...
I don't know If I can use filebeat from the outside to ship the files ?

Comment: You should probably update your question with the specifics of what you're trying to do _and any limitations that you have._ :)